# Stop Camera from moving

Tags: java, android, libgdx, android-camera, android-maps

I've been trying to stop moving my camera at the end of my map, but it continues to move.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {       
//moving tiled map
camera.position.x=camera.position.x+Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()*200;

camera.update();
//...........................................

Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 0);
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


// renderer camera and map
renderer.setView(camera);
renderer.render();
//...................................................

  }

   @Override
   public void show() {

   batch = new SpriteBatch();


   map = new TmxMapLoader().load("maps/map1.tmx");

   renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map);

   camera = new OrthographicCamera();
   }

   @Override
   public void hide() {

   }

   @Override
   public void create() {

   }

  @Override
  public void resize(int width, int height) {
  camera.viewportWidth = width;
  camera.viewportHeight = height;
  camera.position.set(width/2f, height/3f, 0); //by default camera position on (0,0,0)
  camera.update();


  }

  @Override
  public void render() {



  }

 @Override
 public void pause() {


 }

@Override
public void resume() {


}

@Override
public void dispose() {
map.dispose();
renderer.dispose();

}
}
```

I couldn't find any error in my code.

So my question here is, how to stop the camera from moving at the end of the map?

Answer (score 0):

You have at least one layer in the tiled map, so:

```
TiledMap map = ......//whatever method that you are using to load a map
//skip to the part that the map is loaded
TiledMapLayer layer = (TiledMapLayer)map.getLayers().get(0);
int layerWidth = layer.getWidth()*layer.getTileWidth();
```

And now, you know the layer's width **in pixels**, and yo can make sure that `camera.position.x+Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()*200;` never exceeds this length.